# Why does the view disappear after an animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, animation, uiimageview

I've been trying to animate an image using this code.

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
{

    dice.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.png"], nil];


    [dice setAnimationRepeatCount:3];
    dice.animationDuration = 1;


    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Then I have a button that makes the animation play.

```
-(IBAction) animate:(id)sender {

[dice startAnimating];
}
```

Everything works perfectly. The animation plays 3 times with duration of 1 second each time. However after the animation has played 3 times, the dice image view simply disappears from the screen. How do I stop this from happening so the image doesn't disappear and I can do other stuff to the image view?

Comment: @MarmiK `NSArray` can't hold nil, it just indicate end of arguments

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with your code.  The issue must be in other code.

Comment: `dice.animationRepeatCount = 0;` that will make the animation count infinite... in your case the animation is 3 times only.

Comment: No other code really. Everything's hooked up

Comment: and yes MarmiK I don't want it to play indefinitely. I kinda want it to seem like the dice is spinning and landing on the final image however the dice disappears after it's been playing 3 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you setting `dice.image` anywhere?  The animations are different than the image the imageView contains, and "play in front of" the image and then are removed.  I recommend using `UIImageView`'s `startAnimatingWithCompletionBlock` method:

```
- (void) viewDidload {

    dice.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.png"]; // big assumption on my part
                                                     // the assumption is that this is the image you want
                                                     // after animating

    dice.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.png"], nil];

    [dice setAnimationRepeatCount:3];
    dice.animationDuration = 1

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

A "block" is a chunk of one or more lines of code that wait until after the animation finishes to be executed.  If you set the image beforehand it will appear "behind" the animations as they run and may not be what you want.

Comment: ok what you're saying makes sense but when I put that code in my viewDidLoad it gives me an error related to the startAnimatingWithCompletionBlock:

Comment: which is " no visible @interface for 'UIImageView' declares the selector 'startAnimatingWithCompletionBlock'".     And what do you mean big assumption on my part. Thanks. And yes I was trying to learn about randoms so I made a random number and set the view based on the number. For example if(randomInterger == 1) { dice.image = [imageNamed:@"image1.png"]};   The app worked perfectly and displayed random dice faces but then I decided I wanted it to kind of look like it was spinning and landing on a random number so I set the animation to play just above the if statement but the dice disappears.

Comment: Whoops, my mistake!  I am using a category on UIImageView.  My face is red, answer edited.  So, where are you setting `dice.image`?  Before `[dice startAnimating]`?

Comment: no I was setting it after the [dice startAnimating]. Just now I set it right after the if statements and it works like charm, it spins for a while then shows a random number each time. Thank you so much. My logic was that first I would have the animation run and right after when it ran it would set the image to the random dice picture. But I guess not. Can you tell me why I have to set the dice.image before rather than after. Thanks

Comment: @Supert165 I'm not certain why the image was not set when you tried it some other way without actually seeing that code; perhaps the code wasn't executed (was in a part of the code that was not reached), or perhaps the filename was misspelled (UIImage/UIImageView would not complain, just fail to load the image), &c.